# PHP - Get User ID for a particular user

Tags: php, user, id

I am trying to get the User ID of a particular user from Salesforce. Right now my code looks like this:

```
$user = $sfcon->query("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'Bob' AND LastName = 'Smith'");
```

What I want is to return the User ID of this user but their doesn't seem to be a selected field for it. How would I go about doing this?

If I need to be more clear please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `Id` to the list of fields to return.

```
$user = $sfcon->query("SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'Bob' AND LastName = 'Smith'");
```

Comment: Too easy. I didn't see that in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. By the way, the Id field is referenced up in the [System Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/system_fields.htm) section.